# Select prepended option by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopify, liquid

Okay I'm about to pull my hair out.

I'm hoping someone can help me.

**I'm trying to prepend a "Select an Option" value to a dropdown menu and then make that the default selected option when the page loads.**

For a brief background: I have been trying to combine Shopify's "Linked Options" and "Pick an Option" features. Sadly, when you try to implement both, the Linked Options feature overrides Pick an Option. (Pick an Option places a default "Select a ____" to the dropdown menu).

So I have taken a part of the Pick an Option and tried placing it in Linked Options.

Here is the code that I placed in that:

```
selector.prepend('<option value="">Select ' + {{ product.options[forloop.index0] | json }} + '</option>').val('');
```

And here is the entire code:

```
<script>
// (c) Copyright 2016 Caroline Schnapp. All Rights Reserved. Contact:     mllegeorgesand@gmail.com
// See https://docs.shopify.com/themes/customization/navigation/link-product-    options-in-menus

var Shopify = Shopify || {};

Shopify.optionsMap = {};

Shopify.updateOptionsInSelector = function(selectorIndex) {

  switch (selectorIndex) {
    case 0:
      var key = 'root';
      var selector = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(0)');
      break;
case 1:
  var key = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(0)').val();
  var selector = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(1)');
  break;
case 2:
  var key = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(0)').val();  
  key += ' / ' + jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(1)').val();
  var selector = jQuery('.single-option-selector:eq(2)');
  }

  var initialValue = selector.val();

  selector.empty();    
  var availableOptions = Shopify.optionsMap[key];
  selector.prepend('<option value="">Select ' + {{ product.options[forloop.index0] | json }} + '</option>');
  selector[0].selectedIndex = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<availableOptions.length; i++) {
var option = availableOptions[i];
var newOption = jQuery('<option></option>').val(option).html(option).val('');
selector.append(newOption);
  }
  jQuery('.swatch[data-option-index="' + selectorIndex + '"] .swatch-element').each(function() {
    if (jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('data-value'), availableOptions) !== -1) {
      $(this).removeClass('soldout').show().find(':radio').removeAttr('disabled','disabled').removeAttr('checked');
}
else {
      $(this).addClass('soldout').hide().find(':radio').removeAttr('checked').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
  });
  if (jQuery.inArray(initialValue, availableOptions) !== -1) {
selector.val(initialValue);
  }
  selector.trigger('change');  

};

Shopify.linkOptionSelectors = function(product) {

  // Building our mapping object.
  for (var i=0; i<product.variants.length; i++) {
    var variant = product.variants[i];
    if (variant.available) {
  // Gathering values for the 1st drop-down.
  Shopify.optionsMap['root'] = Shopify.optionsMap['root'] || [];
  Shopify.optionsMap['root'].push(variant.option1);
  Shopify.optionsMap['root'] = Shopify.uniq(Shopify.optionsMap['root']);
  // Gathering values for the 2nd drop-down.
  if (product.options.length > 1) {
    var key = variant.option1;
    Shopify.optionsMap[key] = Shopify.optionsMap[key] || [];
    Shopify.optionsMap[key].push(variant.option2);
    Shopify.optionsMap[key] = Shopify.uniq(Shopify.optionsMap[key]);
  }
  // Gathering values for the 3rd drop-down.
  if (product.options.length === 3) {
    var key = variant.option1 + ' / ' + variant.option2;
    Shopify.optionsMap[key] = Shopify.optionsMap[key] || [];
    Shopify.optionsMap[key].push(variant.option3);
    Shopify.optionsMap[key] = Shopify.uniq(Shopify.optionsMap[key]);
  }
}
  }
// Update options right away.
  Shopify.updateOptionsInSelector(0);
  if (product.options.length > 1) Shopify.updateOptionsInSelector(1);
  if (product.options.length === 3) Shopify.updateOptionsInSelector(2);
  // When there is an update in the first dropdown.
  jQuery(".single-option-selector:eq(0)").change(function() {
    Shopify.updateOptionsInSelector(1);
    if (product.options.length === 3) Shopify.updateOptionsInSelector(2);
    return true;
  });
  // When there is an update in the second dropdown.
  jQuery(".single-option-selector:eq(1)").change(function() {
if (product.options.length === 3) Shopify.updateOptionsInSelector(2);
return true;
  });  
};

{% if product.available and product.options.size > 1 %}
  var $addToCartForm = $('form[action="/cart/add"]');
  if (window.MutationObserver && $addToCartForm.length) {
    if (typeof observer === 'object' && typeof observer.disconnect === 'function') {
      observer.disconnect();
    }
    var config = { childList: true, subtree: true };
var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {      
  Shopify.linkOptionSelectors({{ product | json }});
  observer.disconnect();
});  
observer.observe($addToCartForm[0], config);
  }
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it'll take way too much time to grok. Snippet 1 demonstrates how to prepend an option to a select. Snippet 2 demonstrates how to use `insertAdjacentHTML()`. The attribute: `selected` which value can be: `"selected"` or `true/false`, purpose is to designate the default option. Details are commented in the code.

#### SNIPPET 1

```js
// Reference the select
var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
// Create an option
var opt = document.createElement('option');
// Add a value
opt.value = '0';
// Add content
opt.textContent = '0';
// Make it default
opt.setAttribute('selected', true);
// Reference the first child of the select
var first = sel.firstChild;
// Insert box before the first 
sel.insertBefore(opt, first);
```

```html
<select id='sel' name='sel'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
  <option value='4'>4</option>
</select>
```

#### SNIPPET 2

```js
var sel = document.getElementById('sel');

sel.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<option value="" selected=true>Select</option>');

// Reference the first child of select
var first = sel.firstChild;
// This commented out because I don't have the data to use it.
// first.textContent = "Select "+{{product.options[forloop.index0] || json}}+";
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/handlebarsjs/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js'></script>
<select id='sel' name='sel'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
  <option value='4'>4</option>
</select>
```

The first parameter of `insertAdjacentHTML()` is the location of insertion:

> ```
>  <section id='s1'>Content xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</section>
> ▲-----------------▲----------------------------▲---------▲
> ```
>
> `beforebegin`___`afterbegin`________________`beforeend`_`afterend`

The second parameter is the string that will be parsed into HTML. Basically `inserAdjacentHTML()` is `innerHTML` on steroids. Read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).